# Regex after matched string and white space in Ansible

Tags: python, regex, ansible

I'm trying to automate the unseal of Hashicorp vault via Ansible and to do so I need to pipe the standard output of the initialization of Vault to regex and capture the 5 keys that are automatically generated. Can anyone assist with the regex in capturing multiple keys but just the key portion?

Example of an unseal key:

```
Unseal Key 1: `vhK9/+JLLa59BOdR7SClCnuRERrEPqRk3z5yO4aCOKj0`
```

Currently I have the following task:

```
- name: extract keys
  - changed_when: no
  - set_fact:
    vault_keys: `"{{ vault_init_output.stdout | regex_findall ('unseal key', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"`
  - tags:
     - vault

- debug: `msg="{{ vault_keys }}"`
```

However it captures the full line and I only need the keys captured.

Comment: It's not a valid task. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [I downvoted](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Answer (score 0):

solved it. Below are the tasks to initialize Hashicorp vault and capture the keys/token via register and regexp:

```
- name: Initialize the vault
  command: vault operator init
  register: vault_init_output
  environment:
    VAULT_ADDR: "http://127.0.0.1:8200"

- debug: msg="{{ vault_init_output }}"

- name: extract keys
  changed_when: no
  set_fact:
    vault_keys: "{{ vault_init_output.stdout | regex_findall ('(?<=unseal key [0-9]:\\s).*$', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"
  tags:
    - vault

- debug: msg="{{ vault_keys }}"

- name: extract root token
  changed_when: no
  set_fact:
    vault_token: "{{ vault_init_output.stdout | regex_findall ('(?<=Initial Root Token:\\s).*$', multiline=True, ignorecase=True) }}"
  tags:
    - vault

- debug: msg="{{ vault_token }}"
```